# ValueInjecter mapping subobjects from a collection

Tags: collections, mapping, valueinjecter

I try to map a list of objects with ValueInjecter using a LINQ query like this :

```
var thingsCollection = rep.Things.Select(x => new ThingDTO().InjectFrom(x) as ThingDTO)
                                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate).ToList();
```

The problem is that the Thing and the ThingDTO objects contain other objets :

```
public class ThingDTO
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public MaterialDTO Material{ get; set; }
}
```

What kind of injection method should I use to get the sub object map ? Or do I have to do a foreach instead of the LINQ query ?

Comment: you would have to do it manually for each new mapped object you need to instantiate the collection manually and add the new mapped elements

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Works fine. If you want to post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would have to do it manually for each new mapped object you need to instantiate the collection manually and add the new mapped elements